# Ionic 2 http.get returns isTrusted true after PHP API call

Tags: php, json, angular, xmlhttprequest, ionic2

I know that that kind of question was already posted, but... doesn't understand why i got :

```
'isTrusted': true
```

After calling a PHP API from Ionic 2.

My code is :

```
  getProduct(id: string){

if(this._product){
  console.log('Returns : ' + JSON.stringify(this._product));
  return Promise.resolve(this._product);
}

console.log('getProduct : ' + Constants.EZ_GETPRODUCT_URI + ean + ' from PHP API');

return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(Constants.EZ_GETPRODUCT_URI + id)
    .map(res => {
      console.log('headers : ' + res.headers);
      return res.json();
    })
    .subscribe(product => {
      console.log('Datas : ' + JSON.stringify(product));
      this._product = product;
      resolve(this._product);
    }, error => {
      console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    });
});
}
```

In the backend, data returned are :

```
return "{'ean':'7613035010550','title':'Eau Min\u00e9rale Naturelle','image': 'https:\/\/static.openfoodfacts.org\/images\/products\/761\/303\/501\/0550\/front_fr.11.400.jpg','brands':'Vittel','categories':['Boissons','Eaux','Eaux min\u00e9rales','Eaux min\u00e9rales naturelles','Boissons non sucr\u00e9es'],'quantity': '1.5 l.'}";
```

And have always same results :

```
{"isTrusted":true}
```

If i log res :

```
{"_isScalar: false, "source": {"_isScalar": false}, "operator": {}}
```

Just say that if call the API from a browser, i get the correct result with JSON headers.

Note : the API is called on my LAN

(http://192.168.1.xxx/res/GetProduct/nnnnnnnn)

Why can't retrieve the JSON object correctly ?

Regards,

JL

Comment: Have you checked what you are receiving from the network tab? I see you have put what backend returns, but I suppose that is not from the network tab in dev tools?

Comment: Will inspect what's returned by the server through the inspector... and tell u what... Thx

Comment: If i run directly from a browser (i.e Chrome) got headers that are not json headers, maybe my script returns bad headers... but, the content is what i wait for...

Comment: Could you show your PHP script. I'm no real expert in PHP, just used it a little :P But you are returning the data like `echo json_encode(....);` Remembering to use `json_encode`?

Comment: Yes... Use some classes to return json, but, just change my code to return in this way :

Comment: To return what way? So are you getting any data to your front? If so, how does it look like?

Comment: Sorry... Wonder if my server is reachable from my android phone... I log calls and it seems my php controller never reached... Another problem, how to make my phone "see" my local server !!!

Comment: What exactly are you receiving from the backend. Something must be returned since you are getting "something", I've asked several times to post the response you are getting, because it seems unclear here :D Check the network tab, paste the response please :)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue sporadically. I think a bug has crept into ionic/angular. Using woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

So... If i run my app from my IDE with :

```
ionic run android -l -c -d
```

I'm unable to reach external datas and got {isTrusted: true}

But if i run the app directly from my android phone, everything is ok...

Not easy to debug, but...

Thx for help

JL